# CSS Column Layout flashing when loading image

Tags: html, css

I am using the [CSS3 Multiple Columns](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) properties to implement a Pinterest-like layout (implemented by [Bootstrap Cards Columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns)). When the images first loaded, each image card will flash because the browser is trying to compute/re-arrange each image in the columns like below:

[image]

I want to achieve the Pinterest-like experience, like even before the image is downloaded, the cards are arranged in the correct position with the correct size set, and wait for image to fill in. Is it possible to somehow hint/preset the image size or ratio in the html/css? (these images' actual sizes are bigger than the display size, I tried to set the width/height properties in HTML to the actual size and it didn't work well.)

The current HTML is like this:

```
<div class="card-columns">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/78vXO.gif" loading="lazy">
  </div>
  ... more card elements
</div>
```

.card-column style is like:

```
.card-columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    -moz-column-gap: 1.25rem;
    column-gap: 1.25rem;
    orphans: 1;
    widows: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out a solution by inspecting Pinterest's layout:

1. Add a `<div>` wrapper around the image, and set the div wrapper's padding top to be image.height / image.width . For example: `div-wrapper: { padding-top: 135%; }`
2. make the image `position: absolute;`.

In this way the container can be pre-defined using the ratio of the image, and the column can be computed nicely.

Answer (score 0):

you can add min-width and min-height properties for image. Or you can set width and height with object-fit: 'cover'